# How to Group By row format / regex in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have different formats of phone numbers stored as strings in my database:

```
Phone
(812) 283-2013
701 857 7000
207-623-0389
5592369797
...
```

Is it possible to list a sample of each format that I have, so I would know which formats exist?

I'm using SQL Server but I'm interested in the general idea, so the approach for any other relational DB is fine.

Comment: I've removed the other tags, as every dialect of SQL is different, and SQL Server itself has no support for Regex. As for the question, what specifically are you looking for here? You say you want details of the formats; so what values are you expecting exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for distinct patterns of phone numbers.  If so, `translate()` would be a good option

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Phone] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('(812) 283-2013')
,('701 857 7000')
,('207-623-0389')
,('5592369797')
 

Select distinct Frmat = translate(Phone,'0123456789','##########') 
 from @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
Frmat
### ### ####
##########
###-###-####
(###) ###-####
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, but didn't want to make the guess yet. :)

Comment: Nice solution, but note that this won't work pre SQL Server 2017. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @iceblade Very true.   I should have expressed that.

Comment: This solution is pretty good. If `translate` isn't supported, nested `replace` will do. The general idea is the same

Comment: Why coudn't I think of this myself? Simple and elegant.